# Putting require once in a php class

Tags: php

I'm just learning and playing about with php.

I'm trying to separate and clean up my code by putting parts of the php in another file and i'm using require_once to do it, but it doesn't work in a class, is there an alternative?

Here's my code;

```
<?php
  class test1 {
    require_once ( 'test.php' );
  }
?>
```

Comment: Put the require outside the class

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to put just parts of a class in another file.
Maybe an better practice would be to organize your code in multiple classes. 

You might want to take look at extends and autoloading

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php   
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it outside the class (will be included when the class file is included):

```
<?php
    require_once('Bar.php');

    class Foo {
        //Do whatever
    }
?>
```

or use a [`__construct`](http://www.php.net/__construct) (will be included when the class is created the first time (`new Foo()`)):

```
<?php
    class Foo {
        public function __construct() {
            require_once('Bar.php');
        }

        //Do whatever
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't simply put that in a class,
you should use `__construct()` for this

*OR*

put that require_once() function outside of the class

*AND
A suggesion*

Never try to include pages from the GET/POST requests, there is shell called "`c99shell`" which is used for hacking in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  require_once ( 'test.php' );

  class test1 {
  }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
  class test1 {
     function requireOnce() {
         require_once ( 'test.php' );
     }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  class test1 {

    public function __construct(){
      require_once ( 'test.php' );
    }

  }
```

or

```
require_once ( 'test.php' );

class test1 {
 ...
}
```

or you put it in any function you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  class test1 {
    require( 'test.php' );
  }
 test1();
?>
```

You can use require too. And call your class by adding "test1();" to your code.